# What is the most efficient way to convert 3D array into array of 2D arrays in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

Subject says it all.

I just want to do this, but to me, allocating new array is inefficient.

```
julia> a = reshape(1:30, 2, 3, 5)
```

into

```
julia> b = [a[:, :, i] for i in 1:5]
```

Is there a simple way to convert type from `Array{T, 3}` to `Array{Array{T, 2}, 1}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible to do without allocating. However, you might be able to use views instead of actually creating the array, e.g. by doing

```
julia> a = reshape(1:30, 2, 3, 5);

julia> collect(eachslice(a, dims=3))
5-element Array{SubArray{Int64,2,Base.ReshapedArray{Int64,3,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{}},Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},Int64},true},1}:
 [1 3 5; 2 4 6]
 [7 9 11; 8 10 12]
 [13 15 17; 14 16 18]
 [19 21 23; 20 22 24]
 [25 27 29; 26 28 30]
```

Comment: `SplitDimsArray` type from SplitApplyCombine.jl essentially creates a view on two levels (the inner arrays and the outer array) so still it allocates, but only minimally - independent of the size of the inner or outer container (only as much as is needed to create the "wrapper" objects). Also maybe `eachslice(a, dims=3)` is enough for Jongsu if having the possiblility to `getindex` is not required and being able to iterate is enough?

Comment: Actually I need this because of Zygote.jl and Flux.jl. I use CNN and RNNs, then I need conversion to pass output of CNN to RNNs. Both answer is right, but for me, this answer is more appropriate because Zygote can get adjoint. That's why I changed accepted answer. Anyway thanks for answer, @BogumiłKamiński !

Answer (score 5):

You can use SplitApplyCombine.jl and there is a function `splitdimsview` that does exactly what you ask for:

```
julia> a = reshape(1:30, 2, 3, 5);

julia> b = splitdimsview(a, 3)
5-element SplitDimsArray{SubArray{Int64,2,Base.ReshapedArray{Int64,3,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{}},Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},Int64},true},1,(3,),Base.ReshapedArray{Int64,3,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{}}}:
 [1 3 5; 2 4 6]
 [7 9 11; 8 10 12]
 [13 15 17; 14 16 18]
 [19 21 23; 20 22 24]
 [25 27 29; 26 28 30]
```

Note though that the object is not `Vector{Matrix}` but a custom object (but with the same characteristics except it is a view).